# Efficiently identify an event that occurs between a beginning and ending time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite, merge

I have two data frames:

Data frame one has a timestamp, a factor(amount of power generated) and a location.

Data frame two has an event(amount of rain), a timestamp for the beginning time of the event, a time stamp for the ending time of the event and a location.

I want to include, in the first data frame, a column for the amount of rain falling when a certain amount of power was generated.

I was able to create a small dataframe and run a test with the following code:

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame({'factor': ['2','3','4','5','6','7'],
                   'timestamp':['2022-12-01 10:00:00','2022-12-01 10:05:00',
                                '2022-12-01 10:15:00','2022-12-01 10:20:00',
                                '2022-12-15 13:00:00','2022-12-20 06:00:00'],
                   'location':['a','b','c','d','a','d']
                   })

df2 =pd.DataFrame({'event': ['2','3','4','5','6','7'],
                   'time_start':['2022-12-01 9:00:00','2022-12-02 10:05:00',
                                 '2022-12-01 8:15:00','2022-12-01 9:20:00',
                                 '2022-12-25 10:00:00','2022-12-20 05:00:00'],
                   'time_end':['2022-12-01 16:00:00','2022-12-02 10:15:00',
                               '2022-12-01 20:15:00','2022-12-01 20:20:00',
                               '2022-12-25 13:00:00','2022-12-20 06:30:00'],
                   'location':['a','b','c','d','b','c']
                   })

df1['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])

df2['time_start'] =  pd.to_datetime(df2['time_start'])
df2['time_end'] =  pd.to_datetime(df2['time_end'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on="location")
 
df3['quantity_rain'] = df3['event'].where(df3['timestamp'].between(df3['time_start'], df3['time_end']))
df3.replace(np. nan,0)
```

but when I run the code with my larger dataframe, the kernal restarts because I am using too much ram.

This occurs when I try to merge the two dataframes with `df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on="location")`

I was trying to find a way around this, I read that I should try to use SQL. I figured I can merge the dataframes, convert the merged dataframe back to pandas then proceed as usual, but I am not sure of how to do that (or even if that's the best way to go about things?). When I run my code I get the error
`* sqlite://(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: df1`

My code is below:

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite://

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database')
c = conn.cursor()

# Converting dataframes to SQL tables
df1.to_sql('df1_SQL', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
df2.to_sql('df1_SQL', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)

# Merging tables
%sql SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 USING (location)
```

Is there a way to do this with less ram with python? if not is sql the way to go and how can I fix my code?

Comment: First of all the lines beginning with percent sign aren't Python code but an extension of jupyter (or ipython). Mixing them with real Python code may be possible but I wouldn't recommend it. Use the database cursor object to execute SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome the memory overflow problem, here is one aproach.

Create an interval index form start and end columns of `df2` then create a mapping series by setting the index of `df2` to `location` along with the interval index. Now group `df1` by `location` and for each location `map` the `timestamp` values to corresponding events using the mapping series finally `concat` all groups together

```py
ix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['time_start'], df2['time_end'], closed='both')
event = df2.set_index(['location', ix])['event']

pd.concat([
    g.assign(event=g['timestamp'].map(event.loc[k])) 
    for k, g in df1.groupby('location', sort=False)
])
```

After `concat` the result will be

```
  factor           timestamp location event
0      2 2022-12-01 10:00:00        a     2
4      6 2022-12-15 13:00:00        a   NaN
1      3 2022-12-01 10:05:00        b   NaN
2      4 2022-12-01 10:15:00        c     4
3      5 2022-12-01 10:20:00        d     5
5      7 2022-12-20 06:00:00        d   NaN
```

Comment: time complexity vs space complexity - sth has to give